# Databinding a StructuredPropertyEditor specific to type and target in Spring(Grails) - Selective application

Tags: spring, data-binding, grails

Using Grails 1.2.2, I'm working on binding a structured property (CC expiration Date) to a `java.util.Date` but only for specific Domain and Commands objects.

I've found the [StructuredPropertyEditor](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.2.2/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/StructuredPropertyEditor.html) interface, but the only way that I've found to register it is to use the [PropertyEditorRegistrar](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/beans/PropertyEditorRegistrar.html) and register the editor for the java.util.Date class (much [like this example](http://blog.myti.it/post/441330811/custom-property-editor-for-grails))

I don't want all of my dates to use my custom StructuredPropertyEditor.  How do I apply the StructuredPropertyEditor selectively to specific targets like certain Command & Domain Classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Grails most of the [Data Binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.1.6%20Data%20Binding) is by type and convention, whereas in raw Spring you might manually construct this stuff.

After researching this a while, the closest that I could get in Grails was to register a custom editor for with a specific propertyName / Class type.  I wasn't able to make it specific to a specific command object or domain.

```
class CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry propertyEditorRegistry) {
        propertyEditorRegistry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "cardExpirationDate", new PaymentCardExpirationDateStructuredPropertyEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy"), true))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can't you specify the custom type (cc expiration date model) for the registration?. It worked for me for money representation

```
public class CCExpirationPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
      registry.registerCustomEditor(CCExpirationClass.class, new CCExpirationEditor());
    }
}
```